# MPI multiple send and receive in loop

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a big problem with my code and maybe conceptually. All I need is work done in two different functions. One function has only one instance and its main thread, and the second function has many instances on many other nodes.

One of my functions (function A) is sending 3 parts of data to all nodes, and the other function, B, should receive it at each node. Next, function A should wait for results. When they are ready functions B in each of the nodes should send one part of the data to function A, and all starts again.

It should work something like in this sample code:

```
void prepareData() { //function A
  for(int i = 1 ; i < threads;i++) {
    MPI_Send(...); //first part of data
    MPI_Send(...); //second part of data
    MPI_Send(...); //third part of dat
  }
  //Here this function (A) should wait because second function (B) is computing data
  for(int i=1;i<threads;i++) {
    MPI_Recv(...); //receiving data from function B
  }
}

void computeData() { //function B
  while(isDone) {
    MPI_Recv(...); //first part of data
    MPI_Recv(...); //second part of data
    MPI_Recv(...); //third part of data
  //Here all this data are computed and then sending to main function
    MPI_Send(...); //sending data to function A
 }
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this and which MPI function I should use and how?

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Well, what happens when you try the approach you describe?

Are you really using threads here or are you conflating threaded programming with message passing?   Idiomatic MPI would be more like

```
for(int i = 1 ; i < nprocs;i++) {
...
}
```

SEND might block, so you should probably use ISEND and test/wait for completion.

Comment: After many tries I decided to use MPI_Bcast and "connect" this with MPI_Barrier. Now communication works well. So one small hint for anyone who will have problem with communication, "use MPI_Barrier".

Comment: I'm glad "use MPI_Barrier" got you a good result, but that generally indicates something else going on in your code.  MPI_BARRIER enters into the MPI progress engine, but it does a lot more too. I would advise you to put a big comment around that magic MPI_Barrier so that one day when you (or the poor fellow who takes over after you leave!) wonder why your code is not scaling you can (maybe) find the spot to start investigating.

Comment: I solved my problems with MPI. I had error in data conversion and that was a reason of all my problems, now everything works fine.